# refresh listviews at all tabs in tabbed android project?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, tabs, message

I have a tabbed app in android with three tabs and one listview on each tab( activity ) also a thread runs at main activity connecting to website to get list new items every 20 min.

I want to update all these three lists when receiving new items.

I have a static class contains the lists and I updated these lists with new items but How to send message to active activity so that activity refresh itself with new data from static class ?

Is it possible to send a message to current running activity? a simple code plz.

---

I know I have to notify the changes but how? 
I have these lines for each activity (tab) :

```
TabSpec newlistspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("جديد");
newlistspec.setIndicator("جديد", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_newlist_tab));
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, NewList.class);
newlistspec.setContent(photosIntent);
```

Now how to notify? Can you please provide a code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your Activity is a ListActivity you can use notifyDataSetChanged() to tell the activity that your List has been changed and in an Activity i think you can use this code below to update your ListViews :

```
YourListadapter.changeCursor(YourChangedCursor);
YourListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

hope it helps!

Comment: I know this but how to do that. I edited my question please see it thanks.